# Swift 3 Table Column Width Last Column Not Working

Tags: macos, swift3, xcode8, desktop-application, nstableview

Refer to my attached image.
[image]

Notice the last column for some reason is always short on the width.  I can't for the life of me figure out why or how to fix this?

Here is my code for my controller.

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController, NSTableViewDelegate, NSTableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var theTableview: NSTableView!

    var data:NSArray = [""] //@JA - This is used

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //First remove all columns
        let columns = self.theTableview.tableColumns
        columns.forEach {
            self.theTableview.removeTableColumn($0)
        }

        //self.theTableview?.columnAutoresizingStyle = .sequentialColumnAutoresizingStyle

        for index in 0...100 {
            let column = NSTableColumn(identifier: "defaultheader")
            if(index != 0){
                column.title = "Month \(index)"
            }else{
                column.title = "Factors"
            }

            self.theTableview.addTableColumn(column)
        }



        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        data = ["Group 1","Group 2","Group 3","Group 4"]

        self.theTableview.reloadData()
    }

    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }

    func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {
        if let cell = tableView.make(withIdentifier: "defaultcell", owner: nil) as? NSTableCellView {
            cell.textField?.stringValue = data.object(at: row) as! String
            return cell
        }
        return nil
    }

    @IBAction func startsimulation(_ sender: NSButton) {
        //Recalculates the data variable for updating the table.

        data = ["group1","group2"]

        theTableview.reloadData()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSTableColumn` has a property `resizingMask` and `NSTableView` has a property `columnAutoresizingStyle`. Both can be set in IB or in code. Figure out a configuration so the columns behave like you want. The default Column Sizing of the table view in IB is 'Last Column Only', switching to 'None' will fix your problem.

Another solution is setting `minWidth` of the columns.

Comment: Ok let me give this a try.

Comment: Thanks so much setting to this did the trick, self.theTableview?.columnAutoresizingStyle = .noColumnAutoresizing